# How do you implement Authorization Code Grant with PKCE on a single page application without exposing the client secret in the front-end

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, pkce, oidc-client-ts

I have a single page React application. I'm trying to authorize against Salesforce. I created a connected app inside of Salesforce and have a `client_id` and `client_secret`.

I originally tried using the library `oidc-client-ts` to handle my authentication flow. However, every example I can find, shows them explosing the `client_secret` on the client.

It seems every resource on single page authentication is handling it wrong. What is the point of it being a secret if we are supposed to just place it directly in our front end code?

Shouldn't the process be:

1. Request code from identity provider with pkce and redirect uri
2. Identity provider generates code and sends it to the redirect uri
3. Redirect uri is a server-side endpoint that takes the code, and exchanges it for an authentication token by calling the identity provider with the code and `client_secret`
4. The server then receives the authentication token and redirects back to the client application

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**PUBLIC CLIENTS**

The `oidc-client-ts` library is a pure JavaScript SPA solution, for SPAs that do not use a client secret or backend client. When using it the SPA is a public client. A standards-based authorization server should support this option, but some identity systems, eg Salesforce, may not.

**BACKEND FOR FRONTEND**

To integrate with SalesForce you need to store the client secret in a backend component, as you indicate. There is nowhere secure to store the value in a browser.

Using a [Backend for Frontend](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.1) is considered a more secure flow these days, to limit the impact of XSS exploits by avoiding exposing the API credential (access token) to JavaScript code.

Such a backend can safely store a client secret. Yet this requires a more complex flow than that used by `oidc-client-ts`, due to an extra application cookie layer. They should be considered two distinct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[From here](https://dropbox.tech/developers/pkce--what-and-why-):

> The most common and secure OAuth flow is the authorization code flow.
> Unfortunately, that process relies on apps providing a client_secret
> in the final request for an access token. For certain types of apps,
> that makes leaking the secret an inherent, unavoidable risk, which is
> why they instead needed to rely on an implicit flow. These apps
> include, but are not limited to mobile apps, single-page apps (SPA) in
> JavaScript, and serverless apps.
>
> Because these are public clients, there’s no way for them to guarantee
> the security of the secret used for the token exchange. Using the
> implicit flow solves for that, but with the added risk of exposing the
> access token in the redirect URI at the end of the authorization flow,
> which makes the flow vulnerable to different types of network and
> malicious app interceptions.
>
> This tradeoff was acceptable (and necessary) back when apps couldn’t
> make cross-domain requests—making it impossible to complete an
> authorization code flow. However, now that CORS is widely supported,
> there’s no need for that historical compromise; apps can make direct
> post requests to the token endpoint.
>
> Without the cross-origin problem, public clients can take advantage of
> the authorization code flow by using PKCE, which works by substituting
> the static client secret with a string that is dynamically generated.
> By doing so, the PKCE flow eliminates leaky secrets while allowing the
> authorization server to verify that the app requesting the access
> token is the same one that initiated the OAuth flow.
>
> When a user kicks off a PKCE authorization flow in your app, here’s
> what takes place:
>
> 1- Client (your app) creates the code_verifier. (RFC 7636, Section 4.1)

> 2- Client creates the code_challenge by transforming the code_verifier using S256 encryption. (RFC 7636, Section 4.2)

> 3- Client sends the code_challenge and code_challenge_method with the initial authorization request. (RFC 7636, Section 4.3)

> 4- Server responds with an authorization_code. (RFC 7636, Section 4.4)
> 5- Client sends authorization_code and code_verifier to the token endpoint. (RFC 7636, Section 4.5)

> 6- Server transforms the code_verifier using the code_challenge_method from the initial authorization request and
> checks the result against the code_challenge. If the value of both
> strings match, then the server has verified that the requests came
> from the same client and will issue an access_token.